# Extract state with maximum count from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select a.states,MAX(a.cnt) from 

(Select ci_location.state as states,Count(CI_Location.State) Cnt from 
Fact_Transactions ft
Inner join CI_Location on ft.ID_Location = CI_Location.ID_Location
Where id_model like 'smsg%'
Group by State)a

Group by a.states,a.Cnt
```

Output:-

```
State       Count

Alabama      7
Arizona      15
Arkansas     4
California   100
Colorado     7



   Required output:-

    state    output
    California 100
```

**This code isn't extracting STATE with maximum count value from my table...Is something wrong??**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT TOP 1 -- or TOP 1 WITH TIES
  ci_location.state as states,
  Count(CI_Location.State) Cnt
FROM Fact_Transactions ft
INNER JOIN CI_Location ON ft.ID_Location = CI_Location.ID_Location
WHERE id_model like 'smsg%'
GROUP BY ci_location.state
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `row_number()` function approach to get the maximum count state

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT
         l.state as states,
         Count(l.State) as Cnt,
         row_number() over (order by Count(l.State) desc) Sq
   FROM Fact_Transactions ft
   INNER JOJN CI_Location l on ft.ID_Location = l.ID_Location
   WHERE l.id_model like 'smsg%'
   GROUP BY l.State
) a
WHERE sq = 1
```

Note : For your current query you are further grouping the derived table result. Try, to remove `GROUP BY` clause & just use max() to get the highest count state only.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the a.cnt from group by

select a.states,MAX(a.cnt) from

(Select ci_location.state as states,Count(CI_Location.State) Cnt from 
Fact_Transactions ft
Inner join CI_Location on ft.ID_Location = CI_Location.ID_Location
Where id_model like 'smsg%'
Group by State)a

Group by a.states